# Confusing program flow using setTimeout in loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, settimeout

http://codepen.io/scabbyjoe/pen/evJWwX?editors=1011

```
    order.forEach(function(element) {
      $(element).addClass("pressed");
      console.log("Added to " + element);
      timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).removeClass("pressed");
        console.log("Removed from " + element);
      }, 2000);
    });
```

I am stumped by the flow of my program using setTimeout inside a forEach loop.

I am expecting the program, in a single iteration of the loop to add the class, wait, and then remove the class and then move onto the next iteration.

However as far as I can tell the program is add the class, moving to next iteration, adding that class etc, and then once it has iterated fully, moving onto the remove class function which is set to be delayed.

Comment: did you write this, or are you trying to understand code that someone else wrote?

Comment: @Gonzalo.-I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code is adding the class "pressed" to each block **all at the same time**, and then removing all the class "pressed" after 2000 ms **at the same time**.

If you want the code to run so that it moves from one class to another class, you would have to use [jQuery deferred objects](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-deferred-objects/)